# How to create and get componentId with Tridion Anguilla Framework?

Tags: cme

Do you know if exists any way to get the componentId (tcm) after create it with the code placed in this link [How to create a component in the Tridion JS Framework (Anguilla)?](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/12917/how-to-create-a-component-in-the-tridion-js-framework-anguilla)?

Answer (score 4):

If you don't get any errors after the first `item.save()` method and the item is correctly created you should be able to get the Id through `item.getId()` function.

Using the [example](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/12917/how-to-create-a-component-in-the-tridion-js-framework-anguilla) you refer, and remember what Bart points about **asynchrony**, you can listen to `save` and `savefailed` events on your item:

```
var item = $models.createNewItem($const.ItemType.COMPONENT);

//[...]

function onSaveError(event) {
    $log.error(event.data.ExceptionDetail.Message);
}

function onSave() {
    $log.info("Item's Id: " + item.getId());
}

$evt.addEventHandler(item, "load", onLoad);
$evt.addEventHandler(item, "savefailed", onSaveError);
$evt.addEventHandler(item, "save", onSave);
item.load(true);
```

So because asynchronous execution you can't write your code like this:

```
item.save(true);
var Id = item.getId(); //it's going to be undefined because save function is asynchronous
```

Comment: Although the item is correctly created, the instruction item.getId() returns me "undefined"... Any solution?

Comment: Its possible to get the ComponentId with OrganizationalItemID and the componentName or similar with Anguilla?

Comment: @netosone if `item.getId()` returns "undefined", it sounds like the item isn't loaded, so I think you should edit your question and update it with a bit more relevant details and maybe some example code you are using, so you can say where it is failing. Keep in mind that the Anguilla framework is asynchronous, which sometimes requires a different approach, since if items are not (fully) loaded, you won't have all its properties available.

Comment: I've added more information to the response to illustrate what Bart says.

Comment: Great!! I just write this code and works fine!! Thank you